# Checking that something is a linear subspace. (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

The set of maps from an interval [a,b] $\to X$ make up a normed vectorfield, V.

I am to check that the subset, S, of step-functions from [a,b] is a linear subspace of V.

I believe I have to check 3 criterias:

1) if $u,v \in S$ then $u+v \in S$ for all $u,v \in S$

2) if $u \in S$ and $\alpha \in X$ then $\alpha u \in S$

3) The zero vector, $0 \in S$

I've figured out how to show 1) and 2), but I'm not sure how to properly write/check that the zero vector is $\in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha = 0 \in X$ what can you do with criterion 2? Since

$$0 + 0 = 0$$
for all $s \in S$ and by criterion 2 we have
$$(0+0)s = 0s + 0s = 0s$$
Subtracting $0s$ we get
$$0s = \mathbf{0}$$
Where $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero vector. So we may conclude that if $S$ is non empty and $X$ contains 0, then $S$ contains the zero vector.